# How can I install pygame on python with cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, sdl

I cannot install pygame on cygwin properly. I tried to follow that old doc , http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/svmsccdoc/node49.html, but it doesn't work.

Worse issue is SDL not be able to install correctly

Any helps are welcomed as I've been struggling for days.

Comment: What OS are you on? I'd try to avoid building Pygame if possible.

Comment: Hi Malik, windows but with Cywin.

Comment: Can't you just install with the installer?

Comment: not with cygwin alas. If I was using windows, it would be fine but I'm explicitly looking to having it installed on cygwin.

Comment: Did you read this:  http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/svmsccdoc/node49.html   It specifically mentions cygwin

Comment: SDL has a cygwin pre-built package.  tried that?

Comment: I don't understand the deal with Cygwin. Is it some sort of Linux terminal on Windows?

Comment: it is Malik. I wanted to teach some students how to use Linux on Windows without having to install a version of Linux on dual boot or to have a VM.

Comment: Tried it , Photon. `apt-cyg install SDL` --> Installing SDL
Package SDL not found or ambiguous name, exitin

Comment: Then use `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`.

Comment: Nope.  I tried apt-cyg install pygame and it does not work

Comment: That's not the package name.   use the cygwin search, or try:   libSDL-devel

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=SDL&arch=x86

Comment: For SDL Unpacking...
Package libSDL1.2_0 requires the following packages, installing:
libgcc1 libGL1 libX11_6 libXext6 libXrandr2 libXrender1
Package libgcc1 is already installed, skipping
Package libGL1 is already installed, skipping
Package libX11_6 is already installed, skipping
Package libXext6 is already installed, skipping
Package libXrandr2 is already installed, skipping
Package libXrender1 is already installed, skipping
Package libSDL1.2_0 installed

Comment: For pygame after that

 python setup.py

In file included from src/imageext.c:47:0:
src/pygame.h:106:17: erreur fatale: SDL.h : No such file or directory
 #include <SDL.h>
                 ^
compilation terminée.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Why don't you use the cygwin  installer, which also will install dependencies?   The cmd line probably needs a switch for that

Comment: You mean run the windows binaries then re run the Linux part?

Comment: No, I mean the cygwin setup.exe that's linked on their (cygwin.com) main page.  It has a wizard that lets you search for packages easily

Comment: Not inside,  photon

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091942/pygame-running-in-cygwin-no-available-video-device  Look at the accepted answer

Comment: Hi @PythonMaster, thanks but no, the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to deal with that is to install the python binaries for windows.

Once the python binaries installed, install the [pygame binaries](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) for Windows as well and then run the python binaries from your cygwin console.

Then open a python console and type

```
import pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out one of the simplest things: Have you installed the cygwin Packages "libSDL-devel" and "libSDL1.2_0"?

Are you running 32bit cygwin or 64bit cygwin?

Comment: Hi @ZacekV, I've installed the library. So done.

Comment: And you are trying to get it running with SDL 1.2 or SDL 2.0?

Comment: SDL2.0. Everything is installed but it refuses to install properly.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit cygwin?

Just deleted my whole environment... you got me curious ^^

Comment: 32bit win. One solution that did well is to install python for windows , then pygame and run it  through python

Comment: Yeah, read that... but should be possible only with cygwin IMHO

Comment: Yep but how, @ZacekV? :)

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, did not get it running (solely via cygwin) as well.